# Downloading blob video using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to download a blob video source like

```
<video class="vidmap" poster="img/poster" id="marven" kentryid="45215" kuiconfid="222" kwidgetid="2154" kpartnerid="222e"src="lob:http://www.maniala.com/8697dvf-2222-48b1-b732-2gkjdt689"></video>
```

with this JS code

```
   function download( url, filename ) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href',url);
        link.setAttribute('download',filename);
        link.click()
    } 
    download('blob:http://www.maniala.com/8697dvf-2222-48b1-b732-2gkjdt689','First.mp4');
```

but I am getting failure

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have more details on the type of error you're getting? What does it say on the developer console?

Comment: No, actually I am not getting any error and it is downloading something but not video with No File Messages as shown in the above image

Comment: in console I am getting `undefined`